# Error pgmm function: number of rows of matrices must match

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

As part of my research dissertation, I have to perform regressions, however, after performing tests, my model is not homeostatic, and it is possible that there are problems of endogeneity.
So I wanted to test the pggm function by performing the following line:

```
model <- pgmm(perf~ sol+ca+dt_cp+ac_im+tot | lag(perf,1), index=c("id","time"), data=database)
```

But a error appear

```
Error in cbind(yX1[[i]], V1) :
number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

While there are no empty cells in my database.

Do you have an explanation? Have you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because needs to be in English

Comment: Could you show the output of `dim(yX1[[i]])` and `dim(V1)` please

Comment: The output are "NULL" for both

Comment: Without a reproducible example (e.g., via supplying (part of) your data), it will be hard to tell what is going on.